# Maven and CVS at the same time

Tags: maven, cvs

Hy,

I am a newbie in maven and I have read about the "maven deploy command" to deploy your project to a configured repository server and any member of the development team can download it but

1. Is normal to use Maven in this way(deploy) to be used as a repository like CVS and not use any other CVS repository server like CVS, SVN...
2. When you have configured a CVS repository for your project for example, what is the point of using "maven deploy" at the same time?; I mean, is not better to use the CVS repository in order your development team knows about the new code than use maven deploy? can both be used?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

They are totally different tools for a developer. In short, you use Maven for dependency management and you use CVS for source code management. 
Think like that, you, with a bunch of developers, develop a library which will be used in different projects. For your developer team CVS will be used to share and manage your source code. On the other hand, other development teams define your library as a dependency in their pom.xml files to use your library. mvn deploy deploys a compiled code to a configured server and other developers use it as a library, for example as a jar file.
To answer your question:
1. No it is not normal. You can't use Maven as a CVS tool. Their roles in development process is different.
2. As I stated above, mvn deploy generally creates a jar file and deploys it to the server to allow people to reference it as a library. When you use CVS you share your source code(not compiled code) with other developers in your team.